# Java sorting based on object one property with some condition

Tags: java, sorting

I am facing one issue with sorting in java. i have one list of transaction bean my requirement is to sort based on different property, which i am able to do.
Now the problem is, I have on property called "**trnAmt**" in bean which has both debit and credit amount. and i need sorting on debitAmt and creditAmt.  Amount type will be decide bean other propert **trnType** property if trnType is 'C' means it's a debit amount or if trnType is 'D' means it's a debit amount.

Here is my bean

```
public class CardTransaction {

    private String trnType;
    private Date trnBookingDate;
    private String trnAmt;
    private List trnDesc;



---getter n setter method..
}

Here is my method which is failing .

public void applyColumnSorting(final List transDtlsList, final Sorting sorting) {
        final String sortOrder = sorting.getSortOrder();
        final String column = sorting.getSortCol();
        if ("DT".equalsIgnoreCase(column)) {

            Collections.sort(transDtlsList, new Comparator() {
                private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                @Override
                public int compare(final CardTransaction s, final CardTransaction d) {
                    Date sdate = null, ddate = null;
                    sdate = s.getTrnBookingDate();
                    ddate = d.getTrnBookingDate();
                    int ret = 0;
                    if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                        ret = ddate.before(sdate) ? 1 : -1;
                    } else {
                        ret = sdate.before(ddate) ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            });
        } else if ("NR".equalsIgnoreCase(column)) {
            Collections.sort(transDtlsList, new Comparator() {

                @Override
                public int compare(final CardTransaction s, final CardTransaction d) {
                    String sDesc = StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(s.getTrnDesc().toArray(), "");
                    String dDesc = StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(d.getTrnDesc().toArray(), "");

                    int ret = 0;
                    if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                        ret = sDesc.compareTo(dDesc);
                    } else {
                        ret = dDesc.compareTo(sDesc);
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            });
        } else if ("CT".equalsIgnoreCase(column)) { // Sorting for credit amt.
            Collections.sort(transDtlsList, new Comparator() {

                @Override
                public int compare(final CardTransaction s, final CardTransaction d) {
                    int ret = 0;
                    if(s.getTrnType().equals("C")  ) {
                        final BigDecimal samt =
                            new BigDecimal(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank(s.getOriginalAmt()) ? s.getOriginalAmt() : "0.00");
                        final BigDecimal damt =
                            new BigDecimal(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank(d.getOriginalAmt()) ? d.getOriginalAmt() : "0.00");
                        if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                            ret = samt.compareTo(damt);
                        } else {
                            ret = damt.compareTo(samt);
                        }
                        return ret;
                        }
                        return ret;

                }
            });
        }else if ("DA".equalsIgnoreCase(column)) { //sorting for debit amount
            Collections.sort(transDtlsList, new Comparator() {

                @Override
                public int compare(final CardTransaction s, final CardTransaction d) {

                    int ret = 0;
                    if(s.getTrnType().equals("D")  ) {
                    final BigDecimal samt =
                        new BigDecimal(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank(s.getOriginalAmt()) ? s.getOriginalAmt() : "0.00");
                    final BigDecimal damt =
                        new BigDecimal(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank(d.getOriginalAmt()) ? d.getOriginalAmt() : "0.00");
                    if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
                        ret = samt.compareTo(damt);
                    } else {
                        ret = damt.compareTo(samt);
                    }
                    return ret;
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you mean "sorting on debitAmt and creditAmt" it should split the list CardTransaction into two lists, one of debit the other of credit amounts? Or that debit amounts should all appear before the credit amounts?